# pandas groupby operation in a sequential traverse

Tags: python, pandas

What is the proper way of grouping a pandas dataframe by sequentially traverse the data and create a new group everytime a certain condition is verified.

For instance:

```
time = [
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:05'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:06'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:07'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:13'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:01:15'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:02:10'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:03:40'),
    pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:04:15')
]

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, None, 4]}, time)

B
2013-01-01 09:00:00 0.0
2013-01-01 09:00:02 1.0
2013-01-01 09:00:03 2.0
2013-01-01 09:01:05 NaN
2013-01-01 09:01:06 4.0
2013-01-01 09:01:07 5.0
2013-01-01 09:01:13 6.0
2013-01-01 09:01:15 7.0
2013-01-01 09:02:10 8.0
2013-01-01 09:03:40 4.0
2013-01-01 09:04:15 1.0
```

How can I group the above data, creating a new group everytime the timestamp of a line is at least one hour before the previous one.

Desired output:

```
G1
20130101 09:00:00
20130101 09:00:02
20130101 09:00:03

G2
20130101 09:01:05
20130101 09:01:06
20130101 09:01:07
20130101 09:01:13
20130101 09:01:15
20130101 09:02:10

G3
20130101 09:03:40
20130101 09:04:15
```

I can do this in an imperative way, I was wondering if the pandas API can naturally express this type of operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant one minute apart and not one hour so here's a possible solution. You can calculate a variable to group by on like this:

- transform index to series and calculate differences between rows using `diff`
- compare the values to your desired time delta (1 hour or 1 minute)
- calculate a cumulative sum of the comparison result. This way every time there's a large gap in times the value will increase by one.
- group the dataframe by the resulting column.

Here's an example:

```
# using the time list provided in question
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': list(range(11))}, time) 
g = (df.index.to_series().diff()>pd.to_timedelta('1m')).cumsum()
for i, group in df.groupby(g):
    print(group)

                     B
2013-01-01 09:00:00  0
2013-01-01 09:00:02  1
2013-01-01 09:00:03  2
                     B
2013-01-01 09:01:05  3
2013-01-01 09:01:06  4
2013-01-01 09:01:07  5
2013-01-01 09:01:13  6
2013-01-01 09:01:15  7
2013-01-01 09:02:10  8
                      B
2013-01-01 09:03:40   9
2013-01-01 09:04:15  10
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice way of grouping by a condition